# How to recreate a WE1S project?

Tags: topic-model

The [WE1S (WhatEvery1Says)](https://we1s.ucsb.edu/) project is so resourceful and well documented that I really want to use it. Unfortunately, I still don't know where is the repo that the [Workspace documentation](https://whatevery1says.github.io/we1s-templates/creating-a-project/) referring to? I search for the [`new_project.ipynb`](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Awhatevery1says+new_project.ipynb&type=code) file in the whole organization and yet the string only appears in the doc repo. I asked on both their GitHub, Facebook page and Twitter, but yet received a reply

Comment: You can always raise an issue in their github repo asking for the notebook.

Comment: I did on both their GitHub, Facebook page and Twitter, but yet received a reply